# Question in Linear Algebra (Dimension of Vector Space)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have stucked in an exercise in Linear Algebra.

We have a vector space V and the subspaces $V_{1},V_{2}$ of $V$.
If we know that $\dim V=12$, $\dim V_{1}=8$ and $\dim V_{2}=10$,then 
we want to calculate the $\dim V_{1}\cap V_{2}$.

I have found from identity $\dim V=12\ge\dim(V_{1}+V_{2})=\dim V_{1}+\dim V_{2}-\dim V_{1}\cap V_{2}$ and from inequality $\dim V_{1}\cap V_{2}\le \dim V_{1}=8$,that $\dim V_{1}\cap V_{2}\in \{6,7,8\}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is there a question here?

Comment: Without more information you cannot get a better answer than what you have.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos “Then we want to calculate...”

Comment: Is $V$ possibly the union of $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: we dont have more information for V